# UIWebView error message (Unable to Read Document) doesn't fit available space

Tags: html, ios, css, ipad, uiwebview

I display different files onto a webview. Now I had the case were a file was corrupted. In this case the following error is displayed:

> **Unable to Read Document**
>   An error occurred while reading the document

The content of the webview is

```
<html>   
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.6">
        <style type="text/css">
            div {
                font-family: Arial;
                font-size: 18;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div align="center">
            <br><b>Unable to Read Document.</b>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div align="center">An error occurred while reading the document.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now I have this webview on an iPad not taking up the full screen. The content still wants to take up the whole screen width, but the webview size is smaller. I'm already using `scalesPageToFit`, which is set to `YES`.

[image: Here you can see the white area. This is the size of the webview. The content (error message) needs more space, which isn't available.]

What do I have to do to get the error message taking up the available space? Can you perhaps adapt the meta tag? But here you still would have a flicker effect ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` method and changed the viewport width with the help of Javascript:

`[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"viewport = document.querySelector('meta[name=viewport]'); viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=320');"]`

You can place this code in `webView:didFailLoadWithError:` delegate method.

The `C#` version does look like this:

```
webView.LoadError += (object sender, UIWebErrorArgs e) => {
    webView.EvaluateJavascript("viewport = document.querySelector('meta[name=viewport]'); viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=320');");
    // do something else ...
}
```